Where did the "chore" commit come from?
In Semantic Commit Messages and other places there is reference to a "chore" type of commit.
That gist links to various sources, of which only https://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/dev/git-commit-msg.html mentions the "chore" commit. But this disappears from later versions of the same doc. As far as I can tell, that was the origin of the "chore" commit.
This question may suggest the apparently opinion-based one of what "chore" is intended to mean, so to be clear it's asking just the factual one of "what was the origin of this term?"

It might be a factual question, but is it practical (expected to change how you go about the practice of software development)? See also the guidance in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask to ask questions about problems "you actually face". I'm not sure what problem with your code knowing this history could let you solve; indeed, I might argue that this is an off-site resource request (for a link to whatever blog / set of dev guidelines / &c was first to popularize the convention).

Your first link gives an explanation "(updating grunt tasks etc; no production code change)" - my interpretation of that is "build-system maintenance treadmill work" - though that's specific to the JS ecosystem. Other environments have much less fragile or fast-moving (and fast-breaking) build systems so in those cases "chore" commits might be entirely unnecessary.

Conventional Commits specification suggests that it is from https://github.com/conventional-changelog/commitlint/tree/master/%40commitlint/config-conventional#type-enum

We are programmers, not etymologists.

I would argue that "what are best practices for Semantic Commit Messages?" is an extremely practical question, and a well-considered development practice should be aware of things like the originally stated intent of any particular part of it.

Best practices around collaboration/workflow/&c are not on-topic here in general -- that's a matter for [programmers.se], not Stack Overflow. SO is focused narrowly on the mechanics of writing code, not the larger ecosystem of software design and development workflows. (Separately, see Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing? on [meta]). And regardless, you didn't ask what best practices are -- you asked about history.

I would ask on the linked Snippet thread.

Answering my own question (maybe), this looks like it originates with Angular and was adopted by various other projects.
But Angular later dropped it. Some projects like karma-runner followed Angular, but https://commitlint.js.org/ literally forked off from there.
